Microsoft Word's caption field code different for me and colleagues
Me and some colleagues are working on the same microsoft word document through sharepoint. I have a big issue with cross-references.
Whenever I insert a caption, the field code is something like " SEQ Tabella * ARABIC \s 1", whereas when they insert a caption, it is " SEQ Tabella_ * ARABIC \s 1". Still, the captions look exactly the same (meaning that their caption is not "Tabella_ 1.1" but rather "Tabella 1.1").
This means that I am unable to cross-reference their tables, as the field codes differ, and vice-versam unless we create new captions that we only use for cross-referencing purposes.
I believe this to be an issue on my side, as we use the same templates and up until last week I did not have this issue, and I am the only one suffering from it right now.
Is there a way to "merge" these field codes, or to create a new caption with the field code "Tabella_" but that shows "Tabella"?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Are you all using the same method (e.g. the References->Insert Caption dialog box to insert Captions? You can add new CaptionLabel entries such as Tabella_, , and those are stored with your copy of the Word application, but each entry only has a .Name property which the Insert Caption dialog uses for both the SEQ field sequence name and the Caption prefix label.. Here, I also tried creating an AutoCorrect that changes Tabella_ to Tabella, but that doesn't affect either the label or the SEQ field sequence name.
